# How can i write blank php in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i wanna add php code to my laravel app

from here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.iptcembed.php

i tried to do this in my controller like this:

```
<?php


function iptc($rec, $data, $value)

{
    $length = strlen($value);
    $retval = chr(0x1C) . chr($rec) . chr($data);

if($length < 0x8000)
{
    $retval .= chr($length >> 8) .  chr($length & 0xFF);
}
else
{
    $retval .= chr(0x80) . 
               chr(0x04) . 
               chr(($length >> 24) & 0xFF) . 
               chr(($length >> 16) & 0xFF) . 
               chr(($length >> 8) & 0xFF) . 
               chr($length & 0xFF);
}

return $retval . $value;
}

// Path to jpeg file
$path = 'public\images\test.jpg';

// Set the IPTC tags
$iptc = array(
    '2#120' => 'Test image',
    '2#116' => 'Copyright 2008-2009, The PHP Group'
);

// Convert the IPTC tags into binary code
$data = '';

foreach($iptc as $tag => $string)
{
    $tag = substr($tag, 2);
    $data .= iptc_make_tag(2, $tag, $string);
}

// Embed the IPTC data
$content = iptcembed($data, $path);

// Write the new image data out to the file.
$fp = fopen($path, "wb");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
?>
Note
```

and i wanna call the function in my routes:

```
Route::get('/iptc', 'MetaController@iptc');
```

but now it shows me this error:

Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\MetaController::iptc(), 0 passed and exactly 3 expected

does anyone know what is the problem?

I though i can write normal php in laravel?

But what do i wrong?

thank you for your help!! :)

Comment: You've shown a function called `iptc_make_tag`, which does take three parameters. You haven't shown us your `iptc` function, but apparently it also wants three parameters. If you're just using `/iptc` for your URL, then that's zero parameters passed.

Comment: if i pass the parameters like this: Route::get('/iptc/{rec}/{data}/{value}', 'MetaController@iptc'); it shows me a 404 page? so how cann i pass them?

Comment: What URL are you trying to use to access that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer were there actually

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\MetaController::iptc(), 0 passed and exactly 3 expected
```

function @iptc expected 3 params,and yet you pass 0 param

so in your routes you need to change into

```
Route::get('/iptc/{rec}/{data}/{value}', 'MetaController@iptc');
```

and then on url box you only need to call it as

> urlpath/iptc/foo/bar/doe

so controller will recognized it as

$rec = foo,

$data = bar,

$value = doe